# Android LRU Cache out of memory error

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-lru-cache

I'm using LRu Cache to download and display images from http protocol. My app is one Activity with 5 fragments. Each fragment load a Custom ListView with images and text.

My app always crashes after a while.

This is my LogCat:

11-03 18:00:22.613: E/dalvikvm-heap(1558): Generating hprof for process: com.example.example PID: 1558
11-03 18:00:24.004: E/dalvikvm(1558): can't open /data/misc/app_oom.hprof: Permission denied
11-03 18:00:24.064: E/dalvikvm-heap(1558):  hprofDumpHeap failed with result: -1 
11-03 18:00:24.064: E/dalvikvm-heap(1558): After hprofDumpHeap for process
11-03 18:00:24.064: E/dalvikvm(1558): Out of memory: Heap Size=196608KB, Allocated=193561KB, Limit=196608KB, Proc Limit=196608KB
11-03 18:00:24.064: E/dalvikvm(1558): Extra info: Footprint=196552KB, Allowed Footprint=196608KB, Trimmed=12KB

And this is my LRU Class:

```
public class NBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap>
implements ImageCache{
public NBitmapCache(int maxSize) {
    super(maxSize);
}

public NBitmapCache(Context ctx) {
    this(getCacheSize(ctx));
}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight();
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
}

// Returns a cache size equal to approximately three screens worth of images.
public static int getCacheSize(Context ctx) {
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = ctx.getResources().
            getDisplayMetrics();
    final int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    final int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    // 4 bytes per pixel
    final int screenBytes = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4;

    return screenBytes * 3;
}

}
```

I searched in this forum and Google how to solve this problema, but I don't accomplish solve it. Anyone can help me? The target of my application is from sdk 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the the recycling of Bitmaps - see `Bitmap.recycle()`

Comment: I don´t understand how I can implement this method in my class. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to calculate the maximum Memory that available for the application.and use the amount of memory according to your need. 
you can try this method

```
final int maxMemory = (int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() /1024);
```